# What are some synonyms for "live" as used in the broadcast TV context? Our TV station is great because it's always ____!

Tags: phrases, synonyms

"In the moment" sounds a little janky. Any nicer-sounding words that aren't long phrases per se? Really wanna find a word or short phrase that captures "living in the moment" or "something happening now".

Our TV station is great because it's always ____!

Comment: Could you use *on air*?

Comment: That's a good one. Any others also welcome please.

Comment: Perhaps *streaming*, or *trending* for "something happening now." Can you please supply a context and an example sentence where it is intended to be used?

Comment: Creating a poster to market something as "something happening right now" as opposed to something that is stale and can be watched on YouTube later.

Comment: ... by editing the question itself, for example "our TV station is good because it is always ___". There is more information in the [Tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Or maybe “real-time”

Comment: Does *spontaneous* fit?

Comment: What's wrong with *live*? ***Our TV station is great because it's always live!*** Why do you need a synonym for that?

Comment: *Live* is it. . .